# grid filter in foxpro

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have a grid on a form that displays some columns from a dbf table and a textbox.
I want to search the value displayed in the textbox over all columns from a dbf table. Some fields are numeric and other are character
If I want to find a number, should search all record that contain that number in all columns, no matter the column type.
 If I want to search a substring should give me all record that contain that substring.

```
SET FILTER TO ALLTRIM(ThisForm.Text1.Value) $Content or ALLTRIM(val(ThisForm.Text1.Value)) $registrationNumber or ALLTRIM(ThisForm.Text1.Value) $holderNo
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach with the "$" wildcard "contains" approach appears to be ok.  However, your attempt via allt( val( )) would fail as you cant trim a numeric value, it would have to be pre-converted to a string.

Now, that said, you could shorten your query by just doing a $ against a concatenation of ALL columns something like (assuming your registration number is a numeric field)...

```
set filter to ALLTRIM(ThisForm.Text1.Value) ;
   $ ( Content +"," +str(registrationNumber) +," + holderNo )
```

if you have dates or date/time fields you could do DTOC( dateField ) or TTOC( dateTimeField).  So, by building a single string of all values, you dont have to explicitly repeat the OR condition repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
select curGrid
scan
    lcRow = transform(field1) + transform(field2) ... + transform(lastfield)
    if lcSearchValue $ lcRow
       DoWhatever()
    endif
endscan
```

This leverages the fact that transform() will give a string representation of any data type.